# mvc Entity Framwork, insert using select max() from table

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am developing an App using `MV5` and `Entity Frameowrk` to connect to `SQL Server` Database

I need to do an `Insert` where the is getting ID like this.

> Select max(id)+1 from table where field_id = @ID.

The idea is to do it in one transaction. 
Is that Posible to do it in Entity Framework or I should use a `Store Procedure`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?  It sounds like what you *should* be using is an `IDENTITY` column rather than trying to create your own (which will lead to problems).

Comment: It is a Department table... it has an unique ID for each Country-State. But you have said  a good decision.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF compiles the C# expressions you provide it into SQL, and then executes the resulting SQL. So you can write such a query in LINQ, which will in-fact be computed during a single "call" to the database:

```
long id = MyDbContext.MyDbSet.Max(entity => entity.Id) + 1;
```

Do note, that if you are doing this so that you can assign a non existing ID to a new entry- there's no need. EF takes care of this for you, so long as the field is named Id and it is of type long. Just do not assign it any value.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand.. You are saying that I can do a table.Select(max) and then an :saveChanges and it is executed in same transaction? thanks

Comment: No need to apologize. That is not what I said, however. I said that if you use LINQ and create a statement like the one you showed in C#, it will be executed by a single DB call. See my edit

Comment: @Diego The whole point of EF is to enable developers to use their favorite programming language, and never use sql. If ever you are using EF and SQL combined- then you are probably missing out on an EF feature.

Comment: @Diego Also note that it is a bad design choice to "depend" on this pattern. by the time you use this Id, it may already be taken, such is the nature of server side development.